# Как правильно задать специальный символ в строковых property

Tags: java, строки, property

Имеется набор файлов property со строками на разных языках. В одной из строк есть символ ®. Эти строки импользуются для формирования текста на сайте. На французском этот символ отображается на странице правильно, а на английском вместо него изображается какой-то странный вопрос в ромбике. Как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте его как html-код ввести: `&reg;`

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Comment: Тогда, комментарий в ответ перенес.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо символа ® используйте его html-код `&reg;`.